# gdborig.exe stucks for about 30s with high CPU usage when debugging Qt under Windows

Tags: gdb, vscode-debugger, qt6

I'm using VS Code under Windows 11 for Qt development (MinGW 13.1.0, Qt6.5.3) and I got the problem: everytime I try to debug my Qt program, my program comes out about 30s later after the debugger (gdb) starts (status bar turns to orange). In this 30 seconds `gdborig.exe` continues to cause a CPU usage around 15%, max 50%.

[task manager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsuG0.png)

In this 30 seconds my program is not displayed, and maybe not run (I guess).

After that my program comes out to display and all thing goes fine afterwards.

Here is my lauch part in `launch.json` (sry I have to hide something):

```json
{
    "name": "(gdb) Launch / Debug ********* GUI",
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/bin/ndisrpcm.exe",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build/bin",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": true,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW-W64\\13.1.0-rev1\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
    "setupCommands": [
        {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
            "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
            "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }
    ],
    "preLaunchTask": "CMake: build"
},
```

And the Qt program (`ndisrpcm.exe` in this case) is really simple: only a basic QWidget demo. I erased all codes and only left a GUI with no absolute no functions and no controls, and this doesn't fix the problem. Therefore I'm really sure it's not a thing to do with my Qt code.

Does anyone also have this problem and maybe know how to fix it?